# How to create a Sharepoint 2010 List with parent-child relationship and apply approval workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I have 2 Custom Lists in **Sharepoint 2010**

1. **ExpenseList** (Parent List)
2. **ExpenseDetailsList** (Child List)

I want to display the **ExpenseDetailsList** inside the **ExpenseList** to the user.  User shall be able to submit Expense and Expense details from the same form.

1. How can i display a **RepeatingTable** inside **ExpenseList** form using **Infopath 2010**?
2. What is the best practice to accomplish this kind of funcctionality.
3. Also, there is a Approval Workflow attached to this list.

I have read many articles online but unable to understand the correct approach.

Can anybody guide me in the right direction, Please.

Thanks